# Pythagorean Triples : Show that exactly one of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is divisible by $5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I was doing some basic number theory problems from [Rosen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500318) and came across this problem:

> Show that if $(x, y,z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple, then exactly one of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is divisible by $5$.

**Book Solution:**

> - We know that $5$ divides at most one of $x,y$ and $z$
> - If $5$ does not divide $x$ or $y$, then $x^{2}\equiv\pm 1\pmod5$ and $y^{2}\equiv\pm 1\pmod5$
> - Then $z^{2}\equiv 0,2\ \text{or}\ -2\pmod 5$
> - But $\pm 2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$
> - So $z^{2}\equiv 0\pmod 5$, whence $5$ $\mid z$

**My Problem:**

Can someone help me out in understanding the first point of the solution? I am all thumbs.

Comment: Probably because the solution is very well explained already. If you need help, point out which specific part you do not understand/know

Comment: @JackYoon , edited :)

Comment: Should the second bulled be $5\nmid x$ instead of $5\mid x$? (BTW you could include also the name of the book.)

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: What does 'primitive' mean?

---

So the statement we are trying to prove here is if $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive Pytagorian triple, that is to say $hcf(x,y,z)=1$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$, then $5$ divides at most one of them.

If 5 divides all three of them then 5 divides the highest common factor of $x,y$ and $z$ and this is a contradiction.

So suppose 5 divides two of them. Then by the congruence $x^2+y^2\equiv z^2$ (mod $5$) it is clear that the third one must be divisible by $5$ also which is a contradiction. (for example if we assumed $x$ and $z$ to be divisible by $5$ then we obtain $y^2 \equiv 0$ (mod $5$)

Comment: Hi , @JackYoon , `primitive` here mean that $(x,y,z)$ = 1 ... am I correct ?

Comment: yes. You should easily be able to work the statement out from there. It's 'obvious' to those who has intuition for this but for the first learner it might be useful to write the full proof down. (which should be 2-3 lines anyways)

Comment: Hi @JackYoon , a bit more help would go a long way -- can't seem to be able to work it out myself ...

Comment: $(x,y,z)=1$ means 5 divides at most two of them. Suppose 5 divides two of them, then?

Comment: but is it not possible that 5 does not divide either of them ?

Comment: First statement says 5 divides at most one of them. Which means for now 5 dividing none of them is fine. I noticed there is a typo in the second statement of the book proof. It should be if 5 does not divide $x$ or $y$

Comment: Hi , @JackYoon , but when we talk about `primitive` here -- that means that $(x,y)$ $=1$ ; $(y,z)$ $=1$ ; $(x,z)$ $=1$ ; so how can $5$ $\mid$ any of $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: First of all $(x,y,z)=1$ is not equivalent to $(x,y),(y,z)$ and $(x,z)$ being equal to one. (for instance 4,6,7 satisfy the first condition but not the second)

However even with the stronger first condition 5 can divide at least one of $x,y$ and $z$. I don't know where your confusion comes from so I will write the 'full' proof.

Comment: Hi @JackYoon , but there is this theorem which says : If $(x, y, z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple, then $(x, y)$$=$ $(x, z)$$=$ $(y, z)$$=$ $1$ , so how can $5$ even $\mid$  $two$ of $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: the 'theorem' is something I have proved in my answer. Ie I assumed there exist prime $p$ which divides two elements out of $x,y,z$ which leads to contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @JackYoon , I got it :) Thanks for bearing with me :)